# make xml rss feed out of static pages in jekyll

Tags: rss, jekyll

Default `feed.xml` which comes with Jekyll is like this, and cycling through
posts:

```
---
layout: null
---
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
    <title>{{ site.title | xml_escape }}</title>
    <description>{{ site.description | xml_escape }}</description>
    <link>{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/</link>
    <atom:link href="{{ "/feed.xml" | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
    <pubDate>{{ site.time | date_to_rfc822 }}</pubDate>
    <lastBuildDate>{{ site.time | date_to_rfc822 }}</lastBuildDate>
    {% for post in site.posts limit:10 %}
    <item>
        <title>{{ post.title | xml_escape }}</title>
        <description>{{ post.content | xml_escape }}</description>
        <pubDate>{{ post.date | date_to_rfc822 }}</pubDate>
        <link>{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}</link>
        <guid isPermaLink="true">{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}</guid>
        {% for tag in post.tags %}
        <category>{{ tag | xml_escape }}</category>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for cat in post.categories %}
        <category>{{ cat | xml_escape }}</category>
        {% endfor %}
    </item>
    {% endfor %}
</channel>
</rss>
```

What I would like, is to cycle through static pages instead, but if I exchange
all instances of `post` with `page`, in place of `page.content` I get
unrendered liquid tags, so my page content in xml feed contains 
`{{ page.title }}` literally instead of an evaluated title for that page.

Would it be possible to get those variables evaluated?

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll renders only page with a front matter. In this case it must be :

```
---
layout: null
---
... code here
```

Comment: If I see well, that front matter is present.

Comment: So, you repository url can be helpful to debug.